# A growing list of objects in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I had a model for uploading images for slider and binding those images with some articles.

```
class SliderImages(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'slider'
    image_1 = models.ImageField()
    image_2 = models.ImageField()
    image_3 = models.ImageField()
    article_1 = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='+')
    article_2 = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='+')
    article_3 = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='+')
```

Then in admin.py I write:

```
class SliderImagesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': (('image_1', 'article_1'),
                                  ('image_2', 'article_2'),
                                  ('image_3', 'article_3'),)
        }),
    )
admin.site.register(SliderImages, SliderImagesAdmin)
```

It's working good and it's okay. But the ammount of image-article is limited(3). I want admin to decide number of image-article just adding new ones.
I think that new model should look like this:

```
class SliderImages(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'slider'
    image = models.ImageField()
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='+')
```

I guess tha I should use `inlines`, but have no idea how

Answer (score 0):

**models.py**

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class Slider(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta():
        db_table = 'slider'


class SliderItems(models.Model):
    slider = models.ForeignKey(Slider, related_name='slider_items')
    image = models.ImageField()
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='+')
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Slider, SliderItems


class SliderItemsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SliderItems

class SliderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        SliderItemsInline,
    ]


admin.site.register(Slider, SliderAdmin)
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin

Comment: when just : ('title'), then error Unknown column 'slider.title' in 'field list'"

Comment: Updated answer. Needed to import ugettext_lazy as _ for models.py

Comment: 1054, u"Unknown column 'slider.title' in 'field list'"

Comment: Did you 'syncdb' or 'migrate'?